# Excel VBA using if statement to compare variables

Tags: excel, vba

In a for loop statement, I want to insert something like `If a = 5/2 * b` `Then...` `End If`, but "Run-time error '13' Type mismatch" appear. Is there any way I can do this in VBA?

```
 Dim a as Double
 Dim b as Double
 Dim rCell As Range

 For i = 0 to 40
 a = b
 a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min((Cell.Value + i * 5/8), 0.8) 
 If a = b Then 
 Exit For
 End If
 R  = R & "," & thisResult

 Next
```

I want to change `If a = b Then` to something like `If a = 5/2 * b Then`

Comment: Can you share your variable declarations for `a` and `b`, as well as their corresponding values?

Comment: They are both a list of string of number: 2,5,2.5,4,7,9.5 etc.

Comment: You can't multiply a string by 5/2. Please [edit] your question with more code, as well as how you are getting `a` and `b`. This is the best way for you to help us help you!

Comment: What is `Cell.Value`?

Comment: It is a list of number dim as range

Comment: What is the *specific* value of `Cell.Value` and is that the line that throws the type mismatch?

Comment: Type mismatch appears during the line `If a = 5/2 * b`, I try to change `a = b` under `For ` to `a = 5/2 * b` still do not work. `Cell` is a row in the spreadsheet that named as Cell with value 2 4 54 32 1 2 3 33

Comment: `(Cell.Value + i * 5/8)` - this is problematic. `Cell.Value` is a 2-d array. You're trying to add `i * 5/8` to an array? Or to the result of the `Min`?